# Ellipsize for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

Ellipsize for EditText works only with

- inputType - none
- editable  - false

But this is making my EditText uneditable.
How can this be handled considering localization also.

Expected behavior:

- Text in EditText should be shown with ellipses.
- EditText should be editable.

Tried these but no success:

- setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END) as per [setEllipsize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt))
- `android:ellipsize="end"
   android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 1):

```
OnKeyListener keyListener = editText.getKeyListener();
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
  void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
      editText.setOnKeyListener(null);
    }else{
      editText.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);
    }
  }
});
```

This works for me, it ellipsizes the text when focus on the EditText is lost. Doesn't ellipsize while typing though.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set `android:editable="false"` just use this property in your EditText. Ellipsize is not able with editable set to true. Basically you can try set editable property dynamically when you set text to your `EditText`.

```
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:editable="false"
```

Comment: I have tried multiple things but no success. All bottle-downs to 'editable' being set to false but with this I am not able to edit the text. So still this remains a open question. Thanks for your answer.