# Android ellipsize EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So i want to cut off the end of an EditText after the User wrote something in a single line which is longer than the width of the edittext. If the user clicks/touches something else like f.e. the next Edittext, the text of the first EditText should be cut of and displayed with "...".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsize for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596935/ellipsize-for-edittext)

Comment: I think it's not doable like what you want, you may make a workaround for this
Like you may create and edittext and textview both on same place, but when edittext lose the foucse, hide it and view the textview

don't forget to add android:ellipsize="end" for the textview

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file on editText add this attribute

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: i already tried that but it doesnt do anything

Comment: android:singleLine="true" you can also update the single line attribute and also ensure your width is set to wrap_content

Comment: I have singleLine ="true" and have the width set to "0dp"

Comment: You can set the maximum number of lines you want to be displayed under the text view with 
android:maxLines="1"

Comment: I already have that, my problem is that ellipsize doesnt work for EditText and i need a  way to shorten the text and show "...". F.e.: "hello this is a text" to "hello this i..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ConstraintLayout ,android:ellipsize="end" attribute will work if you set "layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent or your end constraint" to the Textview.

```
<Textview android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               
               android:ellipsize="end"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent

               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: It is an EditText and not a TextView, which is why ellipsize doesnt work

Comment: as far as i know,we can not set ellipsize for editeText.@MahsumB